# Python - Match json object with multiple conditions

Tags: python, json

```
urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yandex.com']

jobs = {
    "jobs": [{
        "id": "4535765",
        "urls": [{
            "url": "http://google.com",
            "status": "OK"
        }, {
            "url": "http://yandex.com",
            "status": "OK"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "4535756",
        "urls": [{
            "url": "http://example.com",
            "status": "OK"
        }, {
            "url": "http://google.it",
            "status": "OK"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I need to match the job id that has as urls all the urls in urls.

```
job_id = [j['id'] for j in jobs['jobs'] if all(u in jobs['urls'] for u in urls)]
```

Of course it doesn't work, cant think a way to interact with every url in urls.

Comment: This is independent of JSON; you just have a Python `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

You were really close, you just weren't actually grabbing the `url` values from the url object within the jobs. Try this:

```
job_ids = [j['id'] for j in jobs['jobs'] if all(u['url'] in urls for u in j['urls'])]
```